# MDM (not Intune) cannot report compliance status (to Azure AD) of a device currenctly being managed

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, mdm

I have succesfully enrolled a Device (Windows 10 Pro Version 1803) to our own MDM by authenticating an Azure AD user. Next I have to tell Azure AD that the device is managed by our MDM and that is where the problem happens.

The `patch` that I do is the same like in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/azure-active-directory-integration-with-mdm#report-device-compliance-to-azure-ad

The error I got is **Resource 'xyz' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present**.

What I have done so far is:

1. On Azure AD Portal I added an MDM `OnPremise` App, set its Terms Of Use URL, Discovery URL, generate a secret. Also configured  MDM User scope to `Some`  and selected a `group` where my users are member of.
2. On Required persimision I verified that "Read and write devices" under "Application Permissions" is checked.
3. The user authenticates (using Azure AD crendentials), accepts Terms of Use (of the MDM) and voilá all fine. That is done on the device under Settings => Accounts => Access work or school => + Connect.
4. During the enrollment, I parse the `Bearer Token` and extract the Device ID (e.g. **xyz**), which is the same as the one on the Azure AD portal once the device succesfully managed.
5. To report compliance status I do a patch like this

`PATCH https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/devices/xyz?api-version=1.0 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiO………
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{  "isManaged":true,
   "isCompliant":true
}`

But I got the error described above.

I have tested as well different Device Ids such as

- the one Windows 10 shows on Settigns => System => About.
- Or the one that is present on the element ContextItem attribute DeviceID on the Request Security Token request during enrollment.

  The `bearer token` I use on the `patch` above is retrieved from microsoft graph when the registered MDM app (using its credentials such as appid, secret, etc) authenticates it self to Azure AD.

Whould you please help me to find the source of this error, or maybe give me some hints in order to solve this. I'd apreciate it a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `deviceId` of a [Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#device-entity) object in Azure AD is often confused with the object's `objectId` attribute. (The latter is known as `objectId` in Azure AD Graph, and as `id` in Microsoft Graph. In both cases, `deviceId` is a *different* property.)

In a GET request for a single Device object with Azure AD Graph:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/devices/{object-id}
```

The field identified by `{object-id}` is *not* the `deviceId` attribute of the Device object, it's the `objectId` attribute.

If you don't already have the Device object's `objectId` value, but you *do* have the `deviceId`, you can use either Azure AD Graph or Microsoft Graph to do the appropriate lookup. With Azure AD Graph:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/devices?$filter=deviceId eq '{device-id}'
```

With Microsoft Graph, you would use:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$filter=deviceId eq '{device-id}'
```

Comment: yes, I did use the object-id instead of the device-id and indeed it worked. Thank you very much (=